# MacBook can't access internet

Tags: networking, macos, wireless-networking, mac, dns

I have a MacBook that is connected to Wi-Fi but it can't access the internet. It can still ping servers like Google's 8.8.8.8. Does anyone have any clue as to what's happening? It just started suddenly.

I've tried changing the DNS to that server, as well as renewed the DHCP lease. None of my other devices on the network discovers the Mac either as connected to the Mac. The built in diagnostics tool didn't help, and all the USB accessories are disconnected.

Comment: Try to disable the firewall.

Comment: What happens when you ping a server with its DNS name?

Comment: @Albin I'm afraid I'm not sure what you mean

Comment: what happens if you ping google.com etc.?

Comment: Do you use a VPN at all? Check the contents of `/etc/resolver/` like this: `ls -la /etc/resolver/`. If any files are in there try deleting them and see if that clears things up.

Comment: I think you need to provide a whole lot of information for anyone to be able to help you.

Comment: It can ping servers, without problem. If I ping Google's 8.8.8.8 the packages gets sent and received without issue. Which is why I think it's connected to the internet. 
What more information do you require? I'm sorry for not providing enough. Let me know and I'll add it!

Answer (score -1):

It will help if you provide some additional info.  But here is a sequence of steps to help resolve the problem:

1. click on the "wifi" icon at the top right of the screen. it should show that wifi is connected, and indicates the network it is connected to (please confirm).
2. click on the bottom of the list displayed from step 1 on "network info". it should display the "ip address" and router (please confirm).
3. open a terminal (found in "apps --> utilities -- terminal"), and type
   `ifconfig -a`, to confirm it shows the same ip number as part of the output under the "en0" device, which is the usual device reserved for wifi on modern macs (please report the output if you can't interpret it yourself).
4. Then try using the DNS server with the "nslookup" command. For example typing `nslookup google.com` at the command line should return an ip number like 142.250.69.206, and it should tell you the DNS server it used to get the IP number.
5. try pinging some machines, using both the domain name using command
   `ping google.com`
   and the ip number
   `ping 142.250.69.206`

These commands should confirm that your mac is connected to the internet, and that it can reach machines to get info (ie access the DNS server), and send info (ie, ping machines using both ip numbers and domain names).

If those things are all working then the problem is likely in settings on the browser, or with a VPN

If they are not working then the info should help in resolving the problem. Probably the first step would be to tell the mac to forget the wifi connection, restart, and set the network up again.